# The "304 Not Modified" Processing Message with the Webrick Server Application - Localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, webrick

The `304 Not Modified` processing message is occurring with every `JavaScript` `(.js)` `file type` in the `assets` folder of the project, on the `localhost`. The experienced problem is a `slow loading time` of the web pages.

Is there anything specific with `Webrick` and the `JavaScript` `(.js)` `file types` in combination, which causes this to happen?

*Notice: Webrick is used with Ruby on Rails 3.2 and jQuery UI*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just clear your cache and cookies...it will be fine

Comment: The problem does re-occur with Firefox, simply by having every JavaScript file type of the assets folder be re-loaded at every page load. Though, this problem does not happen with Internet Explorer.

Comment: Where can this setting be found, which you are speaking of?

Comment: @user1860822:..You can find the setting under Firefox's Options-->Privacy tab. Just clear your cookies each time before running the app or just configure Firefox to clear cookies each ruun...!!